# What layout should I use with this odd keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

[image]

I can't find the right keyboard layout to use for my keyboard.

On the bottom left are these keys in this order:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>

That 4th key is what makes it weird. I selected "Generic 104 Keyboard," but when I press that key it's either `<` or `>`. It's a Zippy WK-725.

What keyboard layout should I use so that that key is correctly detected?

Comment: Try generic 101, and see.

Comment: Thanks, it works when generic 101 is selected. And thanks to the editor.

Comment: @Mitch could I trouble you to write an answer for this question to take it off the `unanswered questions` list? Please ping me after and I'll upvote it. OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years so I can't ask him to do it. Thanks :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix   Done.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most keyboards with a US layout use either generic 101-key or generic 104-key.  If the keyboard have the two Win keys and the Menu key, then its a 104-key keyboard.

Since the keyboard you're using only has one Win key, more than likely it uses a generic 101 layout.